# Unrecognized operator: $geoIntersects

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I am running this query and I am getting :
"Uncaught Error: Unrecognized operator: $geoIntersects"

```
RestPolygons.findOne({restRefId: 'Fsmbi94HahsRJH9rT', zoneCoordinates: {$geoIntersects:
                    {$geometry:{ "type" : "Point",
                        "coordinates" : [34.7791114, 32.077278299999996]}
                    }
                }})
```

If I replace $geoIntersects with $geoWithin, i get "Unrecognized operator: $geoWithin"

Answer (score 1):

[https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/geoIntersects](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/geoIntersects/)/

```
RestPolygons.find(
       {
         loc: {
           $geoIntersects: {
              $geometry: {
                 type: "Polygon" ,
                 coordinates: [
                   [ [ 0, 0 ], [ 3, 6 ], [ 6, 1 ], [ 0, 0 ] ] // for use like 
                 ]
              }
           }
         }
       }
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

It has been added in version 2.4 [geoIntersects](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/geoIntersects/)

Which version of mongo are you running?

Comment: I am using version: 3.2.6